# Float Menu, Centering In Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i create my website for smartphone/mobile phone..

But when i acces with Default Browser Android

This float menu position in centering my website..

But when i acces in Chrome, Mozilla, or UC Browser..

This float menu position in top.

i want when i acces Default Browser Android
This float menu position in top.

**This is my screenshot when i acces my website with default Browser Android**

[image]

**This is my screenshot when i acces my website with UC Browser**

[image]

You can acces my website in mobile phone/smartphone
[www.tingali.com](http://www.tingali.com/)

Help me Thank's...

Comment: Please show us some code. Copying snips of your CSS and it's elements would help us.. My first thought, is have you added 'max-width: 100%;' to the element that is out of line? I could be way off, because I can't see any of your code...

Comment: done, iam added  top : 0px;
thank's for comment